# How can I convert multiple files to UTF-8 encoding using *nix command line tools?

Tags: linux, character-encoding, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch-convert files for encoding or line ending](https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending-under-windows)

I have a bunch of text files that I'd like to convert from any given charset to UTF-8 encoding.

Are there any command line tools or Perl (or language of your choice) one liners I can use to do this en masse?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

iconv does convert between many character encodings. So adding a little bash magic and we can write

```
for file in *.txt; do
    iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 "$file" -o "${file%.txt}.utf8.txt"
done
```

This will run `iconv -f ascii -t utf-8` to every file ending in `.txt`, sending the recoded file to a file with the same name but ending in `.utf8.txt` instead of `.txt`.

It's not as if this would actually do anything to your files (because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8), but to answer your question about how to convert between encodings.

Comment: You should quote the var $i, in order to handle filenames with spaces.

Comment: It will do things, it'll add a BOM for one...

Comment: Are you sure iconv will add a BOM?  I was under the impression that it wouldn't with UTF-8.

Comment: I just tested this with iconv (GNU libiconv 1.11), and it did not add a BOM.  It is my understanding that iconv will only add a BOM if one is present in the input, which it would not be in ASCII.  BOM are problematic, and not necessary with UTF-8.

Comment: FYI, Windows has a tendency to drop BOMs in all Unicode files, even UTF-8. This can be seen with Notepad by choosing the encoding in the Save As dialog. The list "Unicode", "Unicode big endian" and "UTF-8" in addition to the classic "ANSI" encoding. All but ANSI include a BOM.

Comment: iconv follows the principle of least surprise, no BOM on input, no BOM on output.

Comment: if your version of iconv does not support the -o parameter you can directly replace it with >> to use the shell redirection.

Comment: What if we don't know the encoding of the input file (and it's possible it might already be UTF-8)?

Comment: @rob I came here cause I couldn't get it to work with normal redirection, but I'm having trouble getting my head around why the append would be required for redirecting `iconv`.

Comment: @Prometheus the -o parameter is the "output" setting. If not used/available the result goes to STDOUT. For my use case I needed the a new file so I used the >> redirection to create the new file.