# Batch convert encoding in files

Tags: linux, windows, macos, batch, encoding

How can I batch-convert files in a directory for their encoding (e.g. ANSI → UTF-8) with a command or tool?

For single files, an editor helps, but how can I do the mass files job?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724083/unix-newlines-to-windows-newlines-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24713621/242933

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) provide Unix tools like `iconv` and `dos2unix` (and `unix2dos`).  Under Unix/Linux/Cygwin, you'll want to use "windows-1252" as the encoding instead of ANSI (see below).  (Unless you know your system is using a codepage other than 1252 as its default codepage, in which case you'll need to tell *iconv* the right codepage to translate from.)

Convert from one (`-f`) to the other (`-t`) with:

```
$ iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 infile > outfile
```

Or in a find-all-and-conquer form:

```
## this will clobber the original files!
$ find . -name '*.txt' -exec iconv --verbose -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 {} \> {} \;
```

Alternatively:

```
## this will clobber the original files!
$ find . -name '*.txt' -exec iconv --verbose -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 -o {} {} \;
```

---

This question has been asked many times on this site, so here's some additional information about "ANSI".  In an answer to a related question, [CesarB mentions](https://superuser.com/questions/28555/convert-file-type-to-utf-8-on-unix-iconv-is-failing/49175#49175):

> There are several encodings which are called "ANSI" in Windows. In fact, [ANSI is a misnomer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040531-00/?p=39103). iconv has no way of guessing which you want.
>
> The ANSI encoding is the encoding used by the "A" functions in the Windows API (the "W" functions use UTF-16). Which encoding it corresponds to usually depends on your Windows system language. The most common is CP 1252 (also known as Windows-1252). So, when your editor says ANSI, it is meaning "whatever the API functions use as the default ANSI encoding", which is the default non-Unicode encoding used in your system (and thus usually the one which is used for text files).

The page he links to gives this historical tidbit (quoted from [a Microsoft PDF](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512014909/http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/8/56803da0-e4a0-4796-a62c-ca920b73bb17/21-Unicode_WinXP.pdf)) on the origins of CP 1252 and ISO-8859-1, another oft-used encoding:

> [...] this comes from the fact that the Windows code page 1252 was originally based on an ANSI draft, which became ISO Standard 8859-1. However, in adding code points to the range reserved for control codes in the ISO standard, the Windows code page 1252 and subsequent Windows code pages originally based on the ISO 8859-x series deviated from ISO. To this day, it is not uncommon to have the development community, both within and outside of Microsoft, confuse the 8859-1 code page with Windows 1252, as well as see "ANSI" or "A" used to signify Windows code page support.

Comment: Don't use the same filename as input and output! `iconv` seems to truncate files to 32,768 bytes if they exceed this size. As he writes in the file he's trying to read from, he manages to do the job if the file is small enough, else he truncates the file without any warning...

Comment: FYI This question is tagged with osx and it doesn't look like either of the convert-all commands work on Yosemite or El Cap.  The iconv version Apples ships doesn't support --verbose or -o, and the other syntax redirecting stdout doesn't work for some reason and just sends it to regular stdout.

Answer (score 45):

With [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/powershell) you can do something like this:

```
Get-Content IN.txt | Out-File -encoding ENC -filepath OUT.txt
```

While *ENC* is something like *unicode*, *ascii*, *utf8*, and *utf32*. Check out 'help out-file'.

To convert all the *.txt files in a directory to UTF-8, do something like this:

```
foreach($i in ls -name DIR/*.txt) { \
    Get-Content DIR/$i | \
    Out-File -encoding utf8 -filepath DIR2/$i \
}
```

which creates a converted version of each .txt file in DIR2.

To replace the files in all subdirectories, use:

```
foreach($i in ls -recurse -filter "*.java") {
    $temp = Get-Content $i.fullname
    Out-File -filepath $i.fullname -inputobject $temp -encoding utf8 -force
}
```

Comment: Converting from ANSI to UTF via your first proposal does erase the whole content of my textfile...

Comment: @Acroneos: then you made a mistake: the in-file is IN.txt, the outfile is OUT.txt ... this way it is impossible to overwrite the original. if you used the same filename for IN.txt and OUT.txt then you overwrite the file you are reading from, obviously.

Comment: Powershell will convert to UTF with BOM. find and iconv might be much easier.

Comment: @pparas that's wrong. Commands related to text files like `Out-File`, `Get-Content`, `Set-Content`... all have an `-Encoding` parameter which allows utf8BOM or utf8NoBOM. `iconv` is much worse in this regard because it never supports UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: \ is not an escape character in powershell so putting it at the end of each line won't work

Answer (score 9):

## Oneliner using find, with automatic detection

**The character encoding** of all matching text files **gets detected automatically** and all matching text files are converted to UTF-8 encoding:

```
$ find . -type f -iname *.txt -exec sh -c 'iconv -f $(file -bi "$1" |sed -e "s/.*[ ]charset=//") -t utf-8 -o converted "$1" && mv converted "$1"' -- {} \;
```

To perform these steps, a sub shell `sh` is used with `-exec`, running a one-liner with the `-c` flag, and passing the filename as the positional argument `"$1"` with `-- {}`. In between, the UTF-8 output file is temporarily named `converted`.

The `find` command is very useful for such file management automation.

Click here for [more `find` galore](https://hamwaves.com/find/en/index.html#list-the-character-encoding-of-textfiles).

Comment: This works on Mac: `find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'iconv -f windows-1252 -t utf-8 "$1" > converted && mv converted "$1"' -- "{}" \;`, to convert from ANSI

Comment: My iconv command from git bash has no `-o` option so I use file redirection `>` : `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'iconv -f $(file -bi "$1" |sed -e "s/.*[ ]charset=//") -t utf-8 > /tmp/converted "$1" && mv /tmp/converted "$1"' -- {} \;`. Any advantage of using this syntax `--` as opposed to passing `{}` directly ? `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'iconv -f $(file -bi {} |sed -e "s/.*[ ]charset=//") -t utf-8 > /tmp/converted {} && mv /tmp/converted {}' \;`

Answer (score 5):

The Wikipedia page on newlines has a section on [conversion utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities).

This seems your best bet for a conversion using only tools Windows ships with:

```
TYPE unix_file | FIND "" /V > dos_file
```

Comment: this is **new line conversion** and has nothing to do with **encoding conversion**

Comment: @phuclv that code will indeed take certain unicode files and translate them to ascii.  I have been doing that for 15+ years.  I don't know of any way to natively change line endings with a batch file.  I have always used the unix2dos utilities.

Answer (score 3):

[UTFCast](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast.aspx) is a Unicode converter for Windows which supports batch mode. I'm using the paid version and am quite comfortable with it.

> UTFCast is a Unicode converter that lets you batch convert all text files to UTF encodings with just a click of your mouse. You can use it to convert a directory full of text files to UTF encodings including UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 to an output directory, while maintaining the directory structure of the original files. It doesn't even matter if your text file has a different extension, UTFCast can automatically detect text files and convert them.

Comment: Seems they cannot convert into the same folder, only into another destination folder.

Comment: The pro version allows in-place conversion. $20/3months. https://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-version-comparison.aspx

Comment: Oh, express (free) version is useless - it only "Detects" utf-8 WITH BOM !! (everyone can do *that*). Only Pro version that Auto-Renews every 3 months at $20 a pop, will auto-detect. Price is steep for a non-enterprise user. AND Beware if you try the basic version, and your file is already utf-8 (without BOM), then this converter will detect it as ASCII, then (re-)"convert" it to utf-8, which could result in gibberish. Be Aware if this before trying the express version!  They have a demo version for the pro that produces no output - pointless IMHO cuz can't verify results before buying!

Answer (score 3):

There is free and open source batch encoding converter named [CP Converter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cp-converter/).

[image: CP Converter screenshot]

Comment: This *looked* like exactly what I was hoping for (a GUI) though no drag-and-drop (you have to use the File menu) and no ANSI option (that I could find). Nothing I did showed up later as UTF-8 in Notepad++. If this had had just a *little* more development this tool would have been nearly perfect.

Answer (score 2):

In my use case, I needed automatic input encoding detection and there there was a lot of files with [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) encoding, for which command `file -bi <FILE>` returns `charset=unknown-8bit`. This is not a valid parameter for `iconv`.

I have had the best results with [enca](https://linux.die.net/man/1/enconv).

**Convert all files with txt extension to UTF-8**

```
find . -type f -iname *.txt -exec sh -c 'echo "$1" && enca "$1" -x utf-8' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Dang... I wish your answer wasn't that deeply buried at the bottom! `enca` is really useful, and _way_ easier to use... when it works. Then again, other solutions fail, too...

Answer (score 1):

```
iconv -f original_charset -t utf-8 originalfile > newfile
```

Run the above command in a `for` loop.

Comment: I'm guessing `original_charset` is just a placeholder here, not actually the magical "detect my encoding" feature we all might hope for.

Comment: This has the advantage of not requiring the `-o` option which is not available on some flavours of `iconv` (namely, macOS, and I suspect FreeBSD as well).
On the other hand, the `for` loop is non-trivial to create if you require it to transverse a deep tree structure of directories...

Answer (score 1):

Use this Python script: https://github.com/goerz/convert_encoding.py It works on any platform. Requires Python 2.7.

Comment: What about Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

I made a tool for this finally: https://github.com/gonejack/transcode

Install:

```
go get -u github.com/gonejack/transcode
```

Usage:

```
> transcode source.txt
> transcode -s gbk -t utf8 source.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

---------------Solution 1-----------------------------
There are two flaws in @akira 's answer.

1. Your original file would be zeroed if encountered any failure.
2. If your path contains any non-ASCII character, it will throw this error
   `Set-Content : An object at the specified path ...txt does not exist, or has been filtered by the -Include or -Exclude parameter.`

This is an improved version, by adding `-LiteralPath` and `if($?)`

```
foreach($i in ls -name *.txt) {
    $relativePath = Resolve-Path -Relative -LiteralPath "$i"
    $temp = Get-Content -LiteralPath "$relativePath" 
    if($?)
    {
        Out-File -LiteralPath "$i" -inputobject "$temp" -encoding utf8 -force
    }
}
```

----------------Solution 2 (Better)----------------
PowerShell can covert very limited encodings, such gb2312, Shift-JIS are not one of them.
Notepad++ has a python plugin can do a better job than the powershell, and relatively safer, you can review what you are about to convert.

1. Use `Everything` find what file you want to convert. Download link is at below
   https://www.voidtools.com/
2. Notepad++ `Menu -> Plugins -> Python Script -> New Scripts`
3. Copy the one of two scripts(see bellow) and modify by your needs, save it to the default location.
4. Drag all files from `Everything` into notepad++
5. Run python-script with python-plugin in notepad++ from `Menu -> Plugins -> Python Script -> Scripts`
6. Done

There are two scripts, the bottom one can convert and save opened tabs into UTF-8

- Script 1
  https://gist.github.com/bjverde/88bbc418e79f016a57539c2d5043c445
- Script 2

```
for filename, bufferID, index, view in notepad.getFiles():
    console.write( filename + "\r\n")        
    notepad.activateIndex(view, index)       
    # UTF8 (without BOM)
    notepad.menuCommand(MENUCOMMAND.FORMAT_CONV2_AS_UTF_8)
    notepad.save()    
    notepad.reloadCurrentDocument()
```

Comment: The method 5 is quite good and nice, thanks for the sharing.

Answer (score 0):

There is `dos2unix` on Unix. There was another similar tool for Windows ([another reference is here](http://ccrma-www.stanford.edu/%7Ecraig/utility/flip/)).

*[How do I convert between Unix and Windows text files?](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html)* has some more tricks.

Comment: `dos2unix` is useful [to convert line breaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dos2unix), but the OP is looking for converting character encodings.

Answer (score 0):

[ConvertZ](http://www.bumpersoft.com/Education-and-Science/Languages/ConvertZ-12649.htm) is another Windows GUI tool for batch conversion

> - Convert file (plain text) or clipboard content among the following encodings: big5, gbk, hz, shift-jis, jis, euc-jp, unicode big-endian, unicode little-endian, and utf-8.
> - Batch files conversion
> - Preview file content and converted result before actual conversion.
> - Auto-update the charset in `<Meta>` tag, if specified in html docs.
> - Auto-fix mis-mapped Big5/GBK characters after conversion.
> - Change filename's encoding among big5, gbk, shift-jis and unicode.
> - Convert MP3's ID3 or APE among big5, gbk, shift-jis, unicode and utf-8 encoding.
> - Convert Ogg tag between Traditional and Simplified Chinese in utf-8.

Alternative download link: https://www.softking.com.tw/download/1763/

[image: ConvertZ file conversion interface]

[image: ConvertZ settings]

Answer (score -1):

**I have created an online tool for that:**

https://encoding-converter.netlify.app

You can upload bunch of files at once to be converted.
**Use it in this order:**

1. enter the encodings
2. select/drag&drop your files

Upload will start automatically.