# App to convert from ANSI to UTF8 on windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, conversion, character-encoding, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch-convert files for encoding or line ending under Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending-under-windows)

Hey!

I have many files that are encoded in the ANSI (iso-8859-1) format and I want to change it to utf8.

I am converting one by one using notepad++ but I was wondering if there is any application that will convert them all (I have many files) in a quick and easy way.

Anyone know of one app that will do this?? (free app would be great)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is a perfect fit for a scripting language to convert Windows-1252 to UTF-8.

- Here is a [Python and Ruby script](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5367).
- Here is a [Bash script using iconv](http://sharealike.org/index.php/2008/12/12/script-to-convert-windows-1252-files-to-utf-8/).

Comment: `iconv` does the job without any nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cp-converter/) SourceForge app. From the website:

> Codepage Converter - Convert HTML/Text
>   files to different encoding formats
>   e.g. ANSI to UTF-8 or Unicode. Convert
>   multiple files with 1 click. Works
>   with all encodings

Comment: Thanks for the app, but I don't think it's working. I can see the file as ANSI in notepad++ :(

Maybe this encodes text, but what I really want is the encoding of the file

Comment: Tried it right now; true, Notepad++ still tells me it's ANSI. Very strange...

Comment: That's because the program does not mark the files with a BOM at the top, which "tells" Notepad++ the file is UTF-8.  It's a Windows thing.  to fix it, go to Settings -> New Document/Open Save Directory.  Then change the Encoding to "UTF-8 Without BOM", and check "Apply when open ANSI file".  Googling will tell you a lot about why you need to do this, and why BOM's are bad (Wikipedia is your friend).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but: If you saved your scripts as 'UTF without BOM' and notepad++ is now opening them as ansi -> you can 'fix' this behaviour by including a string of multibyte characters somewhere in your comments to force notepad++ to recognise the UTF encoding of the file. It's a complete hackjob, but it works ;-)