# Where can I find a batch TXT to Unicode converter?

Tags: batch, software-rec, encoding, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App to convert from ANSI to UTF8 on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/45148/app-to-convert-from-ansi-to-utf8-on-windows)

Does anyone know of a freeware or open source program to convert .txt files to unicode?

Answer (score 2):

As specified by Idigas, .txt is not an encoding. I'm assuming you meant these .txt files used the default encoding when you saved them, which I believe is set to ANSI if you used Notepad on Windows.

You'll need to know **the initial format** before converting them, but you can use [iconv](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/iconv/). You haven't specified your operating system, but you can get iconv for Linux, Windows, and Mac. I believe it is already included in most Linux distributions.

example:

```
$iconv -f ms-ansi -t utf-8 ansi.txt > utf-8.txt
```

Comment: +1 - Good answer. Windows binaries are available, courtesy of GNU Corporation :), from here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm

Comment: If you are using non-Western Windows locale (specifically: system code page), you might need to pick a different input encoding than `ms-ansi`. `ms-ansi` here actually means code page 1252 Western European, which other locales wouldn't match. The naming of this code page “ANSI” has always been problematic; it is actually a Microsoft invention that has nothing to do with ANSI!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that vital information out! As stated, you must know the initial format it was encoded in to be sure.

Comment: ... which is sometimes mightly difficult to determine, expecially if one uses most english characters, and maybe a few others which are in several other sets (like many central european ones).

Comment: following bobince's comment, i believe "windows-1252" is a synonym for "ms-ansi" as far as `iconv` is concerned.  i prefer it since it more accurately describes the actual encoding.

Answer (score 0):

.txt is a format, unicode is an encoding.

Did you mean, maybe, ASCII to let's say, UTF-16 ? [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) perhaps - not batch *per se*, but with its line command capabilities it can be made automated to a certain point. But this is merely speculating - could you please refine your question as to what you're trying to accomplish.