# Free ANSI to UTF8 Multiple Files converter

Tags: windows, conversion, utf-8, ansi

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Batch-convert files for encoding or line ending under Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending-under-windows)
>   [App to convert from ANSI to UTF8 on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/45148/app-to-convert-from-ansi-to-utf8-on-windows)

Hi,

currently i'm in need of a way to convert loads of .txt files in ANSI to UTF8, since i just found out that a app i'm making doesnt recognize accents when they are in ANSI.

I've tried [cp converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cp-converter/), but it doesnt work... not only the files after converting still appear as ANSI, but it also doesnt recognize the accents, replacing them with a ?, which is basically the problem i have in my app.

Comment: If your outputting to HTML in your app, using the HTML entities will help.

Comment: this question has been asked many times before: http://superuser.com/questions/16672 .. http://superuser.com/questions/27060 .. http://superuser.com/questions/45148 .. http://superuser.com/questions/69091 ..

Answer (score 4):

with [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/powershell) you can do something like this:

```
%  get-content IN.txt | out-file -encoding ENC -filepath OUT.txt
```

while ENC is something like unicode, ascii, utf8, utf32. checkout 'help out-file'.

to convert all the *.txt files in a directory to utf8 do something like this:

```
% foreach($i in ls -name DIR/*.txt) { get-content DIR/$i | out-file -encoding utf8 -filepath DIR2/$i }
```

which creates a converted version of each .txt file in DIR2.

Comment: this is a good answer (afaik, i'm not a powershell user) and i don't think it's been posted on any of the related/similar questions.  if you would, please post it as an answer to the master question: http://superuser.com/questions/27060 ... thanks!

Comment: consider it done :)