# Convert ANSI text file(s) to UTF8 on Windows command line

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8, file-conversion, ansi

I would like to convert (an) ANSI-encoded text file(s) (Win 1252) to UTF8 without BOM, ideally via a command-line call. My use-case: I export .tex files from Stata which I want to compile with LuaLaTeX. Stata apparently does not support UTF8, LuaLaTeX does not support anything but and thus chokes on some non-ASCII characters. From inside Stata I can call shell commands, so it would be nice if I could do the conversion on the fly from within my Stata scripts.

So ideally I would like to be able to call a command like e.g. `convert2UTF.cmd  file.tex`. Another good option would be some batch conversion of files within a folder (e.g. convert all files with *stata.tex). In addition it would be great if the solution would work with default Windows tools (minimum Win 7, even better XP).

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://superuser.com/q/27060) before. The [Cygwin/GnuWin32 approach](https://superuser.com/a/49147) is problematic since I would like to be able to convert without having to install extra software on a machine. The [powershell approach](https://superuser.com/a/113682/202721) looks promising, but apparently `out-file -en utf8` saves the file with BOM.

[Another powershell approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13234167/2114932) that seems to convert to UTF8 without BOM is

```
foreach($i in ls -recurse -filter "*.*") {
    if (
        $i.Extension.ToLower() -eq ".tex"
    ) {
        $MyFile = Get-Content $i.fullname 
        [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($i.fullname, $MyFile)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to run it. I saved it as a powershell script into the same folder as the .tex files, but when I run it, it does not touch them. So apparently there is something missing. Needless to say that my powershell knowledge is close to nothing. Also, I would like to pass a filename as an argument, when calling it from Stata.

Comment: There may be a way to use the powershell approach and not write the BOM. See [Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom).

Comment: @martineau: That is quite similar to the code I posted, right? But how do I run it? E.g. when I paste `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines(out.tex, $MyFile)` to the powershell, I get a ParserError...

Comment: Yes, it's similar, however without seeing the exact ParserError you're getting it's hard to say exactly what's wrong -- my guess is you're passing the wrong arguments to `WriteAllLines` or passing them in the wrong order.

Comment: @martineau: Ok, I post `$MyFile = Get-Content in.tex` followed by `[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines(out.tex, $MyFile)` and I get `CategoryInfo: ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordExceptionFullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall`

Answer (score -1):

I think you may try to use VBS script and `ADODB.Stream` object.

[Google search: "vbs convert file ansi to utf-8"](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbs%20convert%20ansi%20to%20utf-8%20file)