# Batch change encoding ascii files from utf-8 to iso-8859-1

Tags: windows, conversion, character-encoding, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch-convert files for encoding or line ending under Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending-under-windows)

I need a tool like this
http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast.aspx

But the tool should do the opposite, convert multiple files from utf-8 to iso-8859-1

Is there any tool (php script, batch file, etc.) for Windows that can do this? 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/27060 http://superuser.com/questions/16672 http://superuser.com/questions/45148 http://superuser.com/questions/28555

Comment: most of those questions are about converting TO utf-8, but any of those batch tools should be able to convert in either direction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `iconv` from [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm), it works the same as the GNU/Linux counterpart:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 filename.txt
```

you can then use it with batch, provided you've added it to your `%PATH%`:

```
for /f %x in ('dir /b *.txt') do iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 %x
```

Comment: Iff the Windows port is at least half-way sane (I know, many of them aren't and GNUWin32 was a long-time offender in that area)  you could simply pass *.txt to iconv. I never really expect it from ported applications but sometimes there are people with an eye for details working on them and then such things are fixed and globbing is done within the application. Might be the case here.

Comment: Great! worked great!!

Comment: I installed this, but the command gives me a "file not found" message but the file is there. I'm supposed to run this on windows console, right?

Comment: "iconv.exe -c -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT input.gpx > output.gpx" didn't work for me at all: https://postimg.cc/image/nzet60ze5/

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a DOS/Windows shell utility to do this. The source code is open source C++, so it can be ported to other systems.

Look for `crlf.cpp`at [david.tribble.com/src/src.html](http://david.tribble.com/src/src.html)
The executable is at [david.tribble.com/programs.html](http://david.tribble.com/programs.html)

Comment: Great! I'll try it. I wish I could select multiple answers. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, you can *upvote* as many good answers as you want.

Comment: link dead? or is it just that my IP is blocked? *The requested URL was rejected. If you think this is an error, please contact the webmaster.*

Answer (score 0):

ConvertEncoding link is now dead - use either of these programs which will encode the files for you:

- [Python Unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Perl Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html)

Comment: Great! I'll try it. I wish I could select multiple answers. Thanks!!

Comment: The link to ConvertEncoding is dead.