# Need a simple program to convert to utf-8

Tags: windows, conversion, encoding, character-encoding, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [App to convert from ANSI to UTF8 on windows](https://superuser.com/questions/45148/app-to-convert-from-ansi-to-utf8-on-windows)
>   [Batch-convert files for encoding or line ending under Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending-under-windows)

I need to find a program to convert a Windows-1250 encoded file to utf8. It needs to be a standalone program (not a python script) and it needs to run on windows (without install). If I can make the conversion using the commandline that would be perfect.

Yes I know notepad can do that but this is meant to be automated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App to convert from ANSI to UTF8 on windows](http://superuser.com/questions/45148/app-to-convert-from-ansi-to-utf8-on-windows)

Comment: appears to be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending-under-windows or one of its many duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/16672 .. http://superuser.com/questions/45148 .. http://superuser.com/questions/28555