# Unicode text lost when saved as ANSI

Tags: text-editors, unicode, text-editing, ansi

When I saved a text file using a notepad with ANSI, I lost all of the information since it became all question marks. 
Is there a way to convert it back to Unicode to retrieve the text?

Comment: You can try something like what's described in this answer: http://superuser.com/a/49129/400911 (if you are on linux). Or look for a "reopen with encoding UTF-8" option in your editor, notepad++ has something like this IIRC.

Comment: There is no such thing as “ANSI”.

Comment: @tchrist [American National Standard Insitute](https://www.ansi.org/) in an encoding it's usually referring to a local code page (ASCII+extended characters) encoding. [What is ANSI format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format). A bit of a late reply but this was pushed to the front page.

Answer (score 13):

Once the characters are converted to `?` marks they cannot be converted back:
a `?` mark is just a `?` mark, it doesn't know where it came from.
If you replace all the letters a, b, c in a text with x,
you cannot restore the original a, b, c letters.

Your only option is to recover from a previous copy if you have one.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to open your text document in notepad++. As commented by @cartographer

Go to encoding menu and chose **Encode in UTF-8** option.

It may help you to retrieve your text back.

Or you can try with all options, may some **encoding format** convert your text to origional one . :)

Answer (score 0):

If you write a text document in UTF-8, you must save it as UTF-8 otherwise this happens.

So no, you have to restart whatever you did.